# When I snap a curve's vertex to the 3D cursor the handles disappear

Tags: bezier-curves, 3d-cursor

I found out my handles disappear when I snap to cursor. How to add handles back to the curve vertex?

I've hooked the end of my curve to an existing empty, it moves with the empty but when I rotate or scale the empty it has no effect on the curve.
Is there an easy way to fix it that doesn't involve replacing that empty?

Comment: it should be rotating and scaling... did you set any constraints (like lock rot, lock scale)?

Comment: I just found out when I snapped the curves vertex to the cursor my handles got removed, guess I should change the qhestion to, how to bring the handles back

Comment: if you mean the visual rot/scale handle on the empty, they are just deactivated: look under the transform manipulators icons on the 3d view bottom header... anyway pressing R or S and then moving the mouse it should rotate/scale anyway... see https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/transform/transform_control/manipulators.html?highlight=manipulators - I suggest to learn better blender basic to avoid issues such this one, as many other are possible...

Comment: I don't understand how your handles "disappear", could you please add  a screenshot to show what is (not) happening in your 3d view?

Answer (score 4):

Blender treats a curve point as 3 *separate* elements: the central control point, the left handle and the right handle. This means that when you choose *Selection to Cursor*, each *individual* element will be snapped to the cursor, essentially putting the two handles and the control point into the exact same location.

As both the handles and the control point are at the same location the control point can no longer be rotated or scaled as it is the distance between the control point and the handles which determines the scale or rotation, and at the moment, there is none.

The handles *are* still there. If you click multiple times on the control point after it has been snapped to the location and press <kbd>G</kbd> you will eventually select a handle and be able to move it as normal.

As you mention, pressing <kbd>V</kbd> twice solves this as it tells blender to change the handle type of the point, which recalculates the handles at the new location.

To avoid this, in future you can choose <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>> *Selection to Cursor (Offset)*, which will instead treat the selection as a *single* element and move the control point and handles but keep the distance (offset) between them.

Answer (score 0):

To add handles back I pressed <kbd>V</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: Thank You. You saved my day. For those who downvoted, you have to do it by selecting the vertices in edit mode.